# How to get token ID in keystoneclient v3

Tags: openstack, keystone

In the past,I got token ID in kystoneclient v2 with this command:

```
token = keystone.auth_ref['token']['id']
```

But when we move to keystone client v3, I just try the same with the above command. but I always get an error. 
Would you please kindly let me know how I can get the token ID.

Answer (score 3):

In keystone client v3, an authentication response returns the token ID in its header instead of in the response body, which named "X-Subject-Token".

You can refer to the changes here:

https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/index.html?expanded=list-endpoints-detail,create-credential-detail,validate-and-show-information-for-token-detail,password-authentication-with-unscoped-authorization-detail

I had tried to get the token by Perl like this:

```
my $res = $agent->post(
    $self->{auth_url} . "/auth/tokens",
    content_type => 'application/json',
    content      => to_json($authKeystone)
);
my $headerData = $res->{_headers};
my $tokenId = $headerData->{'x-subject-token'};
```

It works!

Answer (score 1):

> keystone.auth_ref['auth_token']

Or use curl as below:

> curl -sd '{"auth":{"passwordCredentials":{"username": "admin",
>   "password": "mysecret"}}}' -H "Content-type: application/json"
>   http://192.168.131.129:5000/v2.0/tokens | python -m json.tool

Answer (score 1):

```
from keystoneauth1.identity import v3
from keystoneauth1 import session


auth = v3.Password(auth_url='http://172.16.50.247:5000/v3',
                   username='admin',
                   password='dawncreat',
                   project_name='admin',
                   user_domain_id='default',
                   project_domain_id='default')
sess = session.Session(auth=auth)
token = sess.get_token()
```